# Permission issue on runnable android

Tags: android, multithreading, permissions, user-permissions

I'm trying to make a service that will run every 10 seconds to check a queue and if there is some data in the queue upload the given uri (uri of a picture just taken from the app) to a certain url.

I have created something along these lines

```
public QueueProcessor(final Context context){
    this.mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
}

/**
 * Starts processing the items on a separate thread.
 */
public void process() {
    Runnable running = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                Log.i(RUN_QP_TAG, "Processing queue");
                // more here
                isRunning = true;
                Queue theQ = Queue.getInstance();
                if(theQ.getSize() > 0){
                   WorkQItem itm = theQ.pop();
                   if(itm.hasImage()){
                        pushImageUploadToProcess(itm);
                   }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            finally{
                //also call the same runnable to call it at regular interval
                handler.postDelayed(this, 10000); 
            }

        }
    };

    new Thread(running).start();
}
```

The pushImageUploadToProcess takes the WorkQItem and tries to upload the image from the item (which is saved as String picUri) by opening the uri and writing the bytes. However I get a permissions denied exception when trying to open the picUri location.

```
MediaDocumentsProvider uri content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A531 from pid=795, uid=10327 requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()
```

How can I allow this Thread/Runnable to have access to the URI?
Note I have tried the upload directly from a button event and it does work.

I have the following permissions in the manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
```

Comment: Add the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the actual permission error is not the real issue. The real issue was the way I was choosing and picking the image.
I ended up using https://gist.github.com/Mariovc/f06e70ebe8ca52fbbbe2 this picker and it seemed to work without any issues. 
I tweaked this code a little bit to suit my needs as any image picked from the camera needed to be saved too so that if there are several images being done and each is needed for later use the relative uri initially will get overwritten therefore you need a fixed one (e.g: to be saved).

Answer (score 2):

You should implement runtime permission, for that use below code

```
PermissionsManager.getInstance().requestAllManifestPermissionsIfNecessary(this, new PermissionsResultAction() {
        @Override
        public void onGranted() {
            // Proceed with initialization

        }

        @Override
        public void onDenied(String permission) {
            // Notify the user that you need all of the permissions
        }
    });
```

add below dependency in your app gradle

```
compile 'com.anthonycr.grant:permissions:1.0'
```

Comment: Where should I put this? On the Queue processor? And what exactly should go in the onGranted and onDenied?

Comment: you should put it on the start of your app

Comment: I just did indeed, and when it gets to open the image Uri I Still get the following error: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A531 from pid=462, uid=10328 requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()

Comment: did you allowed permission for all ?

Comment: Yes it prompted for two permissions, phone calls and managing the data and I allowed both.

Comment: Is your testing device having KitKat OS ?

Comment: I'm running on Android version 6.0.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133849/discussion-between-rajesh-panchal-and-madamanu).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I managed to figure out a way to solve my problem - see below.